# How to only store data for current logged in user using Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below is the code which allows the user to store data into Firestore. The problem is, the uploaded data is viewable for all the users logged into the app. 
How would I be able to only allow the current user logged in to store the data for their account only?

With Firebase Database I use the following code (which works, but not for Firestore)

FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
  String userId=user.getUid(); 
 mDatabaseRef =    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FB_DATABASE_PATH).child(userId);

The above lines of code allows the data to be stored and retrieved only for the logged in user. So the data is unique to them only.

How can I replicate that for Firestore?

```
 fetch=findViewById(R.id.fetchDocument);

    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    upload =findViewById(R.id.uploadText);

    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            POJO pojo = new POJO();
            pojo.setValue("Hello World");

            //below code creates collection, creates a inner doc. and uploads the value (pojo)

            firestore.collection("RootCollection").document("MyDoc")
                    .set(pojo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {


                    //gets called if upload is successful
                    Toast.makeText(ichild.this,"Upload is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ichild.this,"Upload is not successful" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });

    fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to only store data for current logged in user using Firestore

You can achieve the same thing if you pass the `uid` to the `document()` method. So the following lines of code used in Firebase real-time database:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUid();
mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FB_DATABASE_PATH).child(userId);
```

Is equivalent in Firestore with:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference uidRef = rootRef.collection("users").document(uid);
POJO pojo = new POJO();
uidRef.set(pojo);
```

Comment: Where about in the code would I put that? I tried it, but it shows rootRef in red?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I missed that line of code where you should initialize the `rootRef` object. Does it work now?

Comment: Sorry didn't see the updated one. It works as the code doesn't appear red. But, still doesn't save the data for the current logged in user. When I log in with another user account, I can see the other users data.

Comment: Why are you saying "still doesn't save the data for the current logged in user."? But is saving for which user? I'm sure is saving for the logged in user. Cannot save for other user. You are also saying "I can see the other users data", where can you see this?

Comment: What I mean is, when I log in with user account1 and upload data lets say "Hello" and fetch it, I can see the word "Hello" (which is what I want). But when I log out and log in with user account2 and whenever I click fetch it shows "Hello". But it shouldn't show that, as that was input by user account1. So it should only show data input by the logged in users.

Comment: I understand now but you're going outside the scope of your original question. The initial question was: `How can I replicate that for Firestore?` and I just provided you the answer and I'm sure it works. For the second question, I'd suggest create a new question that explains what your current issue is so me and other users can answer and help you.

Comment: I've voted. I also will add a new question, but have to wait 90 minutes. Would you know how to solve the problem I am facing with the code?

Comment: I cannot solve this in a comment, that's why I have asked you to add another question. Beside that, what your code does is just adding data to the database and you are asking about getting it. So it's best to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wait 90 minutes and post a new question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a firestore rule to prevent a user from adding data to another user. Just check the auth userid in firestore and compare it to the userid on the document.