# How do i save data of a user so that it doesn't show to other users of the app in firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So, i'm making a notes app and have implemented firestore for CRUD operations, How do i save data of a user so that it doesn't show to other users of the app?

Comment: You question is not cleared.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749504/how-to-only-store-data-for-current-logged-in-user-using-firestore, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768164/how-users-can-only-see-their-own-data-in-cloud-firestore and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+i+save+data+of+a+user+so+that+it+doesn%27t+show+to+other+users+of+the+app+in+firestore%3F

Answer (score 1):

Store each user's data in separate documents.

All notes can be separate documents under a subcollection Notes under each user.

Users -> UserId -> Notes -> NoteId